# Getting the value of an option through jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I have searched for this but I can not find it anywhere! ;(

I have a select list with options - the first option has a value that I want to withdraw. It is not the selected one - but I am storing a value I would like to take out!

```
<select class="selection_select">
<option value="ref_button_id">Kategory</option>
<option value="ref_database_id">Item 1</option>
<option value="ref_database_id">Item 2</option>
</select>
```

It is called using:

```
$(".selection_select").change(function() {

});
```

Comment: @FelixKling - It's not a duplicate (at least, not of that question). That other question is about the selected value; this question is about getting the value from an option that is _not_ selected.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value of the first option from within an event handler for the select element:

```
$(".selection_select").change(function() {

    var firstVal = $("option:first", this).val();

});
```

Just in case that's not completely self-explanatory, it says to select the first option element (`"option:first"`) within the context of `this` (within an event handler `this` is the element that the event occurred on).

If you're not in the select element's event handler then you can't use `this` in that manner, so from elsewhere you'd do something like the following:

```
$(".selection_select option:first").val()
```